# Beamer Frame is displayed wrong

Tags: beamer, highlighting

i made a Code for alerting through a frame.

It adds an empty (just looks empty very light text) frame in front of the greyed out frame (Picture below).

It only appears to add a frame, if i use Column Layout. Any ideas to get rid of this "redundant" frame?

```
\subsection{H263 / MPEG-4 Teil 2}
\begin{frame}[<+-| alert@+>]{H263 / MPEG-4 Teil 2}
\begin{columns}
    \column{.55\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Weiterentwicklung Richtung H261
                \item Webvideos
                \item Sorenson Spark Format
                \item H\"ohere Aufl\"osung
                \item DVD
                \item .3gp, .avi
                \item Project Mayo (DivX)
            \end{itemize}
    \column{.45\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=150pt]{divx.jpg}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

[image: Alert Image]

EDIT: Maybe there is a way to add alert statement to column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overlay specification for the frame is picked up both by `columns` and the `itemize`, so you get that extra slide. You can prevent this by subtracting 1 to the `beamerpauses` counter when the `itemize` begins:

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[<+-| alert@+>]{H263 / MPEG-4 Teil 2}
\begin{columns}
    \column{.55\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}\addtocounter{beamerpauses}{-1}
                \item Weiterentwicklung Richtung H261
                \item Webvideos
                \item Sorenson Spark Format
                \item H\"ohere Aufl\"osung
                \item DVD
                \item .3gp, .avi
                \item Project Mayo (DivX)
            \end{itemize}
    \column{.45\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=150pt]{divx.jpg}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The `demo` option for `beamer` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: Also works to have "[<+-| alert@+>]" after the itemize of the left column, but your version is better ;)